# XML Schema Name Space

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

New to XML but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Directions say: using Russian Doll design create a schema named menu.xsd, specify the target namespace for the schema and save changes. In menu.xml, specify the location of the schema file and save changes. Validate.

Document is not validating. Getting error:

> "Validation of current file using XML schema:
>
> ERROR: Element '{http://example.com/chestershartland/menu}itemName': This >element is not expected. Expected is ( itemName ).

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<menuItem   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://example.com/chestershartland/menu"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/chestershartland/menu menu.xsd">
   <itemName>Oatmeal Breakfast</itemName>
   <description>
   <![CDATA[Our oatmeal is served warm with fresh fruit, pecans, raisins,
      and 100% maple syrup. Available all day.
   ]]>
   </description>
   <price>6.95</price>
   <icon>&#9824;</icon>  
   <icon>&#9829;</icon>

</menuItem>
```

My menu.xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://example.com/chestershartland/menu"
            targetNamespace="http://example.com/chestershartland/menu">

    <xs:element name="menuItem">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="itemName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="price" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="icon" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

 </xs:schema>
```

Thanks in advance for helping! It seems to have something to do with namespaces, but I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [XSD validation error: Element '{http://www.example.com}Scope': This element is not expected. Expected is ( Scope )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445055/xsd-validation-error-element-http-www-example-comscope-this-element-is-n)

Key was elementFormDefault="qualified"